# Docker manifest list with multiple tags

Tags: docker, bitbucket-pipelines, amazon-ecr

I am trying to create a manifest list with multiple tags. I believe this should be possible as I have done it with `buildx` in the past. Unfortunately I am doing this with Bitbucket Pipelines, which doesn't have `buildx` support.

So far I have been able to produce two docker images from my Dockerfile, `my_image:arm64` and `my_image_amd64`, and I have pushed these both to AWS ECR.

I have then used:

```
docker manifest create my_image:latest my_image:arm64 my_image:amd64
docker manifest push my_image:latest
```

To create a manifest list containing the two images, that way a user can `docker pull my_image:latest` and Docker will get either the Arm64 or x64 version of my image depending on the current system architecture.

This all works correctly, however I am also wanting to add additional tags to the manifest list that provides the version and build number, e.g. `my_image:build-123`, `my_image:1.5`.

I cannot work out how to do this.

I have tried using `manifest create my_image:build-123 my_image:latest` but it fails because my_image:latest is a manifest list, not an image.

Preferably I would like to do this all in a single step, but any advice would be appreciated.

Update:

It appears to be possible to achieve the desired result by re-running the `docker manifest create` `docker manifest push` commands that I used to create the original manifest list, but it is a little clunky when trying to add a large number of tags.

Comment: Note that Buildkit support was released a year ago https://bitbucket.org/blog/announcing-support-for-docker-buildkit-in-bitbucket-pipelines. What buildx command is failing for you? Are you using private runners or an outdated on-premise Bitbucket installation?

Comment: Even though Buildkit was released it still has restrictions, the blog article you shared even links to the list of restrictions:

https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/run-docker-commands-in-bitbucket-pipelines/#Docker-BuildKit-restrictions

    >multi-architecture builds
    >the --platform option (such as docker run --platform linux/arm/v7)
    >the Docker BuildKit Buildx plugin

We are using private runners and it seems you can get around the `--platform` limitation, but not the buildx one